# Is it possible to extend (Override) git command?

Tags: git

Is it possible to override git command or run another git commands before calling its alias. Like so: `git checkout .` -> `git stash && git stash apply && git checkout .`. After accidental checkout i think about it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override a git command through a git alias.

You can do a bash script called git, which you can put in your $PATH first.
Or you can define a function called git in your `.bashrc`.

That script would look for checkout as a first argument and would apply your sequence of commands.

See an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357426/6309).

```
function git {
  if [[ "$1" == "checkout" && "$@" != *"--help"* ]]; then
    shift 1
    command git mycheckout "$@"
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

In that case, you would implement your checkout in a script call `git-mycheckout`: Any script called `git-xxx` can be called by git as `git xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a shortcut for checkout : `alias.co = checkout`, and am now so used to type it that I get surprised when I use a machine without the shortcut.

You could plug your command on such a shortcut.

---

A word on `git stash` : another way to create such a stash :

```
git stash store $(git stash create)
```

This has the advantage of not modifying the files on disk (and possibly triggering some actions watching for files modification ...)

(`store` and `create` are mentionned in `git help stash`)