# Is there a way to verbose 'git add' output by default?

Tags: git

I can verbose the output of the `git commit` command by default with `git config --global commit.verbose true`.

This makes an entry in the `.gitconfig`:

```
[commit]
    verbose = true
```

I tried the same with the `git add` command:

```
[add]
    verbose = true
```

resp.: `git config --global add.verbose true`

However, this does not work (also tab-completion doesn't show me the configuration option `add.verbose` whereas it does for `commit.verbose`).

Does anybody know if there is an option to enable this function?

I am aware of work-arounds like setting aliases, but it remains a work-around and not a 100% solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange: the need for a similar "`add.verbose`" config never came up in the [Git mailing-list](https://public-inbox.org/git/).

"`commit.verbose`" itself introduced in [commit aaab842, May 2016, Git v2.9.0-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aaab84203b9654fb73df41d3cb71a6aad3a091fa) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997), as part of the ['`pb/commit-verbose-config`' patch](https://public-inbox.org/git/1462046616-2582-1-git-send-email-pranit.bauva@gmail.com/).

See [commit aaab842](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aaab84203b9654fb73df41d3cb71a6aad3a091fa), [commit de45dbb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de45dbb8188ecbc74c1e8a95bf861c6acdda393d), [commit e0070e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0070e8bd575c069ddc0a469c43076290210e79e), [commit 98baeb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98baeb794d90e1bf0561355bc6543f9d9072a390), [commit 7d17715](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d1771524c8bc39856f7b30769c2f47c6061ba2f) (05 May 2016), and [commit 36e6a5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36e6a5baf1d45e125fcdb99781a0c6448109b44d), [commit 8425b7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8425b7ea6a00c443ca3649545ac6e9ddfa196ef6) (12 Apr 2016) by [Pranit Bauva (`pranitbauva1997`)](https://github.com/pranitbauva1997).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), and [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5d5f1c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d5f1c236b63596a59293a893d914dab1c8dd377), 23 May 2016)</sup>

I don't know why the same feature was not considered for `git add`.

So yes, alias or [`git` script wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939946/6309) as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16410521/6309) is a good alternative, but not, as you noted, a complete solution..

Comment: I also wondered that I can't find a question for this here on SO, while I found a relating verbose question for almost any other command (git fetch, git commit, ...)
I for myself find `add --verbose` most important since I often work with wildcards and want to be sure if no unwanted file has sneaked in my wildcard expression.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I understand. I simply to `git status` after any `git add`, and do my checks there.

Comment: Yes, I do this, too, since I mostly forget `git add -v` :-) I will accept this as this answers the question, namely there is no option to enable afore-mentioned function.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 no option for now... that could be a future patch to be proposed in the Git mailing list ;)

Comment: I am afraid i am not versed into those mailing lists at all :D I just know them from Linux kernel development and I guess its the same with Git.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct solution, but if your main concern is to obtain concise information about your actions, you can try
`git add --interactive`

Comment: In what way curl debugging is related to `git add --verbose`?

Comment: Can you explain, what this is supposed to do?

Comment: @phd  check - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables:
"Git uses the curl library to do network operations over HTTP, so GIT_CURL_VERBOSE tells Git to emit all the messages generated by that library. This is similar to doing curl -v on the command line."

Comment: I know that. But I don't see any connection between curl and `git add --verbose`. `git add` doesn't use curl because it doesn't use network — it's an entirely local action. Can you explain the connection?

Comment: @phd I see, my bad. That'll come handy for clone and pull commands which involves network interaction.