# Is there a git global config to show progress on clone

Tags: git, git-clone

I know I can use the `--progress` flag when cloning a git repo. However I have to add this to every clone command. There are other times when a script does the cloning and I don't have the chance to add that flag. Is there a global git config that will force `--progress` *on every clone*?

Comment: "Is there a global git config that will force `--progress` on every clone" I don't think so. Since I guess you already left out the possibility to have an alias that does that, the only choice you have is "overriding" the `git` command to extend the clone, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702572/how-to-make-commitizen-override-default-git-commit-command#answer-50068612)

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara nice. you should make this an answer and I'll check it