# How to implement custom checks before starting a git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks

I would like to implement a custom check which has the option to abort a merge before it's begun, preventing `git merge` from touching the working tree or repository *in any way*.  The `pre-merge-commit` hook runs too late for this; [the man page entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) says:

> This hook [...] is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit.

I couldn't see any other hook or config parameter usable for this.  `prepare-commit-msg` doesn't even get run when I do a test of `git merge`.  It feels like there should be a `pre-merge` hook which runs at the very beginning of the merge process.

Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround?  I guess I could write a `git-merge` wrapper which performs the check before invoking the real `git-merge`, and then alter `$PATH` to find that only when I want this check active.  But that feels pretty ugly, and I'm not even sure it would work.  **EDIT:** it doesn't work, because git doesn't allow aliasing of built-in subcommands, as explained in [Is it possible to override git command by git alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias)

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9748a6820043d5815bee770ffa51647e0adc2cf0/builtin/merge.c#L864), there's no call to any function that runs hooks (there are multiple versions) in any of the functions that run earlier in the merge process. Might be worth asking on the mailing list if a change request would be welcome.