# Is there a way to set push callback on my own hosting gitserver like github?

Tags: git, github

I host my own git server, and I really like the feature that you can set a "push callback" on github.

for example:

http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/962_git/receiveUrl.jpg

Is there a way I can set this feature on my own git server?

Answer (score -1):

It seems not, here is a related thread: [Local executing hook after a git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797074/local-executing-hook-after-a-git-push)

Comment: Thx, then i'll figure other way out.