# Open a pull requests' URL in the browser after a git push?

Tags: bash, git

My employer uses an on-prem bitbucket server, and it echoes back a pull request URL after I do a `git push`. Is there a way to have a global hook which lets me open this URL directly in my browser every time I `git push` from anywhere, be it a terminal or an IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Not really: there is no [post-push client-side hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038644/6309).
So, as [mentioned in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812238/6309), you could need to make a Git wrapper script in order to:

- detect the push
- parse its [stderr output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309)
- extract the URL
- call a brwoser with it.