# Run a script on git push

Tags: git, github

I have a bunch of Selenium tests that I want to run when someone does a `git push`.

Having a look around, it seems that this isn't good practice and I've not found any examples of anyone doing this.

The only thing I've found is to run a script after a `git commit`, which I don't really want to do.

The code is to be pushed to github, but ideally I'd like the script to run on the developers local machine

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797074/local-executing-hook-after-a-git-push/3812238#3812238), create a local wrapper for `git push`and you should be good to go.